# Magento 2: Stable way to Get a the Base Directory of a Module

Tags: magento2, module, api

In Magento 1, the static `getModuleDir` method of the `Mage` class

```
Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Mage_Core')
```

provided a stable, "works across versions" way of getting the base folder of a Magento module.

Does Magento 2 have something similar?  I found the `Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader` class that has a `getModuleDir` method.

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/Module/Dir/Reader.php
/**
 * Get module directory by directory type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $moduleName
 * @return string
 */
public function getModuleDir($type, $moduleName)
{
    if (isset($this->customModuleDirs[$moduleName][$type])) {
        return $this->customModuleDirs[$moduleName][$type];
    }
    return $this->moduleDirs->getDir($moduleName, $type);
}
```

I could inject this class as a dependency in my own class and call this method. However, this method is not marked with any sort of `@api` flag, which means it might change unexpectedly.

Is there a safe/stable way for extension developers to determine which folder their module is in (in order to load extra configuration or data files that ship with the module)?  Or do we need to roll the dice the the above class, and/or do directory traversing tricks with `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`?

Comment: Since getModuleDir is a public function it is probably somewhat safe, since developers can use it in plugins and Magento will (hopefully!) be hesitant to remove or alter it.

Comment: @dmatthew Based on experience, your hope is somewhat misplaced.

Comment: @dmatthew what happens when someone deploys my code to their system and updates to a version of Magento that changes this?

Comment: The Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::getPath function looks to fit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ComponentRegistrar` by injecting `ComponentRegistrarInterface` and get a module's directory like this:

```
$path = $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Your_Module');
```

Since all modules are required to register their directory with this class in their `registration.php` file, it doesn't seem like something magento would change.

Comment: +1 I like it -- although since the only method that all modules call is `public static function register` that's the only one I'd trust to stick around.  A good alternative when nothing official comes through :)